# free-JqGrid: resizeStart event not works?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I try to migrate from old version of jqGrid (4.6.0) to new version (4.9.1).

I've noted that resizeStart event is not triggered, but resizeStop works fine. Is that OK?

I'm not sure, but looks like the bug is in call of "feedback" function

```
$bDiv = $(self.bDiv)

feedback.call(getGridComponent(COMPONENT_NAMES.BODY_TABLE, $bDiv), "resizeStart", x, i);

feedback = function () {
        // short form of $.jgrid.feedback to save usage this.p as the first parameter
        var args = $.makeArray(arguments);
        args.unshift("");
        args.unshift("");

        args.unshift(this.p); //this.p is undefined! this is dom table

        return jgrid.feedback.apply(this, args);
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reporting the bug! The line

```
feedback.call(getGridComponent(COMPONENT_NAMES.BODY_TABLE, $bDiv), "resizeStart", x, i);
```

should be fixed to

```
feedback.call(getGridComponent(COMPONENT_NAMES.BODY_TABLE, $bDiv)[0], "resizeStart", x, i);
```

I posted [the fix](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/ee6ece1bee9d44077ea21812f8a443f9be86a2b0) to GitHub. You should just reload the latest sources of free jqGrid.

To use `resizeStart` and `resizeStop` callbacks and `jqGridResizeStart` and `jqGridResizeStop` events one can use the following code:

```
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    ...
    resizeStart: function (e, iCol) {
        ...
    },
    resizeStop: function (newWidth, iCol) {
        ...
    }
}).bind("jqGridResizeStart", function (e, eOrg, iCol) {
    ...
}).bind("jqGridResizeStop", function (e, newWidth, iCol) {
    ...
});
```

So one can use either callbacks or events. One can register only one callback for one grid, but one can bind jQuery events (`jqGridResizeStart`, `jqGridResizeStop` and other) multiple times. One can make binding even *before* jqGrid will be created. The empty `<table>` should just exist already.

Comment: You are welcome! And thank you for free-jqGrid=)
p.s. I am using registration of callback in my project